# Visual Studio debugger wait for managed code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am writing C# plugin (DLL library) for a native\unmanaged application. The problem is that when I start debugger, the application runs and almost immediately exits (probably because my DLL is not loaded on application startup, but later). Checking "Enable native code debugging" helps, but significantly slows down application performance which is undesirable, because I only want to debug my C# code. Is there any way to debug DLL without enabling that option? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Two choices, not sure if Community Edition supports both... First choice, set up a Unit Test project to test out the functionality... Second choice, write a managed test harness program that consumes your library and exercises the functionality. You can debug from either one. All you really need to debug is something in managed code that calls your library.

Comment: WinDbg with `sxe` makes this a cinch, of you are not tied to VS.

Comment: Another option I have used in similar situations is to temporarily add the line `Debugger.Launch()` in the library. When this line is hit, the application will pause and trigger a prompt allowing you to attach a debugger. You would obviously not want this in the production version.

Comment: @pquest Changing my code will not make any difference, since it is not being hit at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. :)
Enable "Use managed compatibility mode" in Options->Debugging->General.